# How to customize Laravel WhereBetween if the value is not found

Tags: laravel

Im using Laravel WhereBetween like this

```
$from = '2015-01-02';
$to = '2015-01-30';
$users = User::whereBetween('created_at', [$from,$to])->get();
```

If the date value not found in User model, then the date will not show right?

I still want to show the date, even the date not found then I set value to 0.

Then the output will be like this

```
[
    {'2015-01-02': 201},
    {'2015-01-03': 0},
    {'2015-01-04': 0},
    {'2015-01-05': 7},
    ...
    {'2015-01-30': 0}
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seriously ? if user not found in inside `$from`, `$to` you want to set date zero or user empty ?

Comment: `If the date value not found in User model, then the date will not show right ?` what do you want to say in this line can you explain ?

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation, added the output in question

Comment: Your query gives you whole users in the given range but not in day wise manner

Comment: I've added answer, please take a moment to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute following query at first to get all user created at the given range,

```
$data = User::select([
    DB::raw('DATE(created_at) AS date'),
    DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS count'),
 ])
 ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from,$to])
 ->groupBy('date')
 ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
 ->get();
```

With above query, you will get count of user for each day and this will not give **0** value if no users created at that day.

Now, what you have to do is to change above collection to array and insert **0** values if no users created.

```
$userCount = $data->toArray();

$dataByDay = array();

foreach($userCount as $count){
    $dataByDay[$count->date] = $count->count;
}
```

Now, insert zero values as:

```
$dateFrom = Carbon::parse($from)->format('Y-m-d');
$dateTo = Carbon::parse($to)->format('Y-m-d');

$days = $dateTo->diffInDays($dateFrom);

for($i=0; $i<$days; $i++){
    $dateString = $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d');
    if(!isset($chartDataByDay[ $dateString ] {
        $dataByDay[ $dateString ] = 0;
    }
}
```

Now, `$dataByDay` array gives what you want.

Hope you understand.